Is this injective morphism of varieties surjective?
Let $f:X \to Y$ be a morphism of algebraic varieties (i.e. integral separated schemes of finite type).
If $f$ is injective, and both $X$ and $Y$ have the same (Krull) dimension, is it true that $f$ is surjective?

Consider the inclusion $\Bbb A^1\to \Bbb P^1$. Are there any other hypotheses you'd like to add?

@KReiser Thank you for pointing this out. Indeed, I'm in a situation where $f$ is projective, hence closed.

What do you mean by "injectivity"?

@Sasha I mean set-theoretically injective.

Let $X$ be a conic with no points (say, over $\mathbb{R}$), $Y = \mathbb{P}^1$, and let $f$ be a morphism that factors through a point. Then it is injective (on points) but not surjective.
